# "Cat catches a bird and eats it"

Tags: scala, immutability, traits

"Scala in Depth" has an unusual example "Cat catches a bird and eats it".
http://www.manning.com/suereth/Suereth_MEAP_CH01.pdf

```
trait Cat
trait Bird
trait Catch
trait FullTummy
def catch(hunter: Cat, prey: Bird): Cat with Catch
def eat(consumer: Cat with Catch): Cat with FullTummy
val story = (catch _) andThen (eat _)
story(new Cat, new Bird)
```

My questions are:

1. Neglecting the functional part, what would the implementations look like?
2. Is it a real-world practice to combine traits like that or it is artificial? What if there are 10 traits to combine in anonymous class?

My implementation (with functional part left out) looks like this:

```
  case class Cat {
    def catchIt(_prey: Bird): Cat with Catcher = {
            new Cat with Catcher {
                override val prey = _prey // This is ugly
            }
        }
  }

    case class Bird

    trait WithFullTummy

    trait Catcher {
        val prey: Bird

        def eat() = {
            println(s"Ate the ${prey}")
            new Cat with WithFullTummy
        }
    }

  val cat = new Cat                               
  val catWhoCaughtBird = cat.catchIt(new Bird)
  catWhoCaughtBird.prey
  val catWithFullTummy = catWhoCaughtBird.eat()
```

Answer (score 0):

(1.) I would think the following could be a simple implementation.

```
trait Cat {
  val catBreed: String
  val name: String
}

trait Bird

trait Catch {
  val prey: Bird
}

trait FullTummy {
  val food: Bird
}

case class NastyCat(
  val name: String,
  val catBreed: String, 
  val prey: Bird) extends Cat with Catch

case class FullCat(
  val name: String,
  val catBreed: String, 
  val food: Bird) extends Cat with FullTummy

def catch(hunter: Cat, prey: Bird): Cat with Catch = 
  NastyCat(hunter.name, hunter.catBreed, prey)

def eat(consumer: Cat with Catch): Cat with FullTummy = 
  FullCat(consumer.name, consumer.catBreed, consumer.prey)
```

(2.) Yes, combining traits like this to specify anonymous return Types can be very useful, it saves having to write out a trait that all it does is extend two other traits.  More commonly you see duck typing e.g. `def eat[T <: { val food: Bird }](consumer: T)`.  When the number of traits gets large, for readability sake people would write a trait.